# Martingale convergence theory question

Tags: measure-theory, martingales

[image]

I'm confused on what this proof would look like.

I know that by Martingale Convergence Theorem:

$$X= \lim Z_n / \mu^n$$ exists a.s.

I also know that Kesten Stigum Theorem:

Assume that $E[L] >1$ and that $p_1 \neq 1$. Then $X>0$ a.s. on the event of survival iff $E[L\log_{+} L] < \infty$

Is that theorem useful in proving what i want to prove?

Edit: Let $\xi{i}^n , i, n, \geq 1$ be i.i.d. nonnegative integer random variables. Define a sequence $Z_n, n \geq 0 $ by $Z_0 =1$ and

$Z_{n+1} = \xi_1^{n+1}+...+ \xi_{Z_n}^{n+1}$ if $Z_n >0$, $0$ if $Z_n=0$

$Z_n$ is the galton-watosn process.

$ \mu = E\xi_m^i \in (0,\infty)$

Comment: What are $Z_n$, $\varrho$ and $\mu$...?

Comment: It appears that you aer asking a question about  a branching process but the question completely missing the context. Define all symbols and tell us what the question is about. Do you expect us to read your mind?

Comment: sorry, i just edited the question with clarification about the notation.

Comment: also, i know that if I have $F_n = \sigma (\xi_i^m: i \geq 1, 1\leq m \leq n)$, and whatever i defined in the post as $\mu$, then $Z_n/\mu^n$ is a martingale w.r.t. $F_n$